# Can't enable Entity History in ASP.NET Zero

Tags: c#, configuration, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using ASP.NET Zero. Project Version: **5.1.0** and .NET Core 2.0 template. I'm trying to enable Entity History for my entity so that I can see the deleted and old column values for the table.

**Entity class:**

```
[Table("TestingEntity")]
[Audited]
public class TestingEntity : AuditedEntity , IMayHaveTenant
{
    public int? TenantId { get; set; }

    public virtual string Code { get; set; }
}
```

**ApplicationModule class:**

```
public class MyCompanyApplicationModule : AbpModule
{
    public override void PreInitialize()
    {
        // ...

        Configuration.EntityHistory.IsEnabledForAnonymousUsers = true;

        Configuration.EntityHistory.Selectors.Add(new NamedTypeSelector("Abp.AuditedEntities", type => typeof(IAudited).IsAssignableFrom(type)));
    }

    // ...
}
```

Running the following queries give no results.

```
SELECT * FROM [AbpEntityChangeSets]
SELECT * FROM [AbpEntityPropertyChanges]
SELECT * from [AbpEntityChanges]
```

**Reference:** https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Entity-History

## Update

It is not giving proper results when I'm deleting an entity item.

It's inserting records for each property with old and new values the same in `[AbpEntityPropertyChanges]` table.

And there is no clear information that this entity item is deleted, its deletion time, and DeletedBy.

Is this due to using `AuditedEntity` in my entity class? I'm using hard delete, so I thought not to add these columns to the table: is deleted, its deletion time, and DeletedBy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entity History is disabled in ASP.NET Zero. You can enable it:

```
Configuration.EntityHistory.IsEnabled = true;
```

## Update

> It is not giving proper results when I'm deleting an entity item.
>
> It's inserting records for each property with old and new values the same in `[AbpEntityPropertyChanges]` table.

That has been resolved in PR [#2977](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/pull/2977), which will be released with ABP v3.5.

> And there is no clear information that this entity item is deleted, its deletion time, and DeletedBy.
>
> Is this due to using `AuditedEntity` in my entity class? I'm using hard delete, so I thought not to add these columns to the table: is deleted, its deletion time, and DeletedBy.

You won't find those in `AbpEntityPropertyChanges` table, since those aren't property changes.

- information that this entity **was** deleted: [`EntityChange.ChangeType`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/ac9c170e339e5a88907ca9d372489ee4bfccd6d8/src/Abp/EntityHistory/EntityChange.cs#L33)
- its deletion time: [`EntityChangeSet.CreationTime`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/ace6e289af88481d014eababb6f587b028abb7b3/src/Abp/EntityHistory/EntityChangeSet.cs#L54)
- DeletedBy: [`EntityChangeSet.UserId`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/ace6e289af88481d014eababb6f587b028abb7b3/src/Abp/EntityHistory/EntityChangeSet.cs#L85)

## Additional information

- relationship between `AbpEntityChangeSets` and `AbpEntityChanges` tables: [EntityChange.cs](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/eb9508d0c1b14e5d3f0f53c826d2e3c5bb779bf8/src/Abp/EntityHistory/EntityChange.cs#L35-L38)

  ```
  public class EntityChange : Entity<long>, IMayHaveTenant
  {
      /// <summary>
      /// Gets/sets change set id, used to group entity changes.
      /// </summary>
      public virtual long EntityChangeSetId { get; set; }

      // ...
  }
  ```
- possible values of `EntityChange.ChangeType`: [EntityChangeType.cs](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/b4f5bf2e12f2e5902f3ae10683f3c047ee121375/src/Abp/Events/Bus/Entities/EntityChangeType.cs)

  ```
  public enum EntityChangeType : byte
  {
      Created = 0,
      Updated = 1,
      Deleted = 2
  }
  ```

> Do we have a plan to add UI for this feature? So that we can see Entity History from UI.

This has been added in ASP.NET Zero **5.4.0**.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue by doing the below change in file **ProjectName.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityFrameworkCore\ProjectNameEntityFrameworkCoreModule.cs** by setting the following value to `true`, You need to enable Entity History.

```
Configuration.EntityHistory.IsEnabled = true;
```

You can refer https://github.com/aspnetzero/aspnet-zero-core/issues/818#issuecomment-365250173.