# Entity History is not working in aspnetboilerplate

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am using aspnetboilerplate and added below configuration in preintiliaze in module. I have also added data annotation Audited to my entity but still it is not working. My entity is inheriting from AuditedEntity as don't need deleted feature. Please help

Configuration.EntityHistory.IsEnabled = true; Configuration.EntityHistory.Selectors.Add(new NamedTypeSelector("Abp.AuditedEntities", type => typeof(AuditedEntity).IsAssignableFrom(type)));

I have taken reference from here [Can't enable Entity History in ASP.NET Zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48761496/cant-enable-entity-history-in-asp-net-zero/48768242#48768242)
Below is entity definition

```
[Audited]
public partial class QuestionResponse : AuditedEntity<long>
{
    public long ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public long QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string Response { get; set; }
    public string Remark { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public Application Application { get; set; }
    public AbpUsers CreatorUser { get; set; }
    public AbpUsers LastModifierUser { get; set; }
    public Question Question { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`AuditedEntity<long>` is not assignable to `AuditedEntity`.

Add a selector based on the interface `IAuditedEntity` instead.

```cs
Configuration.EntityHistory.Selectors.Add(
    new NamedTypeSelector("Abp.AuditedEntities", type => 
     // typeof(AuditedEntity).IsAssignableFrom(type)));
        typeof(IAuditedEntity).IsAssignableFrom(type)));
```

## Reference

From [aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate's AuditedEntity.cs](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/fb93187b86298d49d1666c48f2e1b98624e68820/src/Abp/Domain/Entities/Auditing/AuditedEntity.cs):

```cs
public abstract class AuditedEntity : AuditedEntity<int>, IEntity
{
}

public abstract class AuditedEntity<TPrimaryKey> : CreationAuditedEntity<TPrimaryKey>, IAudited
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Their are 3 different implementation of AuditedEntity one with int an other 2 with generic type TPrimaryKey. you can see in above code snippet itself.  Also primary key  type can vary in my case as per entity

Comment: No it is not working . It is working with entity ported with framework like abproles,abpusers but failing other entity added

Comment: Create a repro project on GitHub that is forked from [aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template).